# Efficiently pass Java data to Javascript for chart plotting purpose

Tags: javascript, java, charts

I am aware that there are numerous Java chart libraries available but most of their plotting style is old fashioned such as JFreeChart and Gral. JavaFX chart is nice but it is **not support boxplot**. So I am thinking of Javascript which is more fashioned style and more interactive. But I am worried about the performance when converting the datasets into Javascript as String as my datasets is up to 10k.

Any suggestion about

1. Java chart library which is more fashioned style and interactive.
2. Efficiently pass datasets from Java to Javascript. Is it good to use J2V8?

Comment: Q1 is off topic and Q2 is too broad. See [*Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript).

Comment: Also put some more detail on where you want to run these code and any sample of what you tried.